# Symfony 4: Returning only active records

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I would like to only get records where the active indicator is true:

```
class Question {
   /**
    * One Question has one Figure
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="QuestionFigure", mappedBy="question")
    */
    private $figure;

    public function getFigure()
    {   
     $criteria = Criteria::create()->where(Criteria::expr()->eq("active", true));
     return $this->figure->matching($criteria);
    }
```

When I do this, I get the error:

```
Attempted to call an undefined method named "matching" of class
```

I believe this is because the matching method can only be applied to an ArrayCollection which $this->figure is not. What would be a similar way of achieving this same result?

Edit based on answer provided by Ihor Kostrov:

getActive() is returning nothing. Testing this out, this works:

```
public function getFigure()
    {
         if (!empty($this->figure) && $this->figure->getId() === 1) {
            return $this->figure;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

But changing the id to 2 does not work ($this->figure->getId() === 2). I am thinking this is because of the one-to-one relationship doctrine only fetches one row?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have OneToOne, so you cat try this

```
public function getFigure(): ?QuestionFigure
{   
    if (!empty($this->figure) && $this->figure->getActive()) {
        return $this->figure;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Yes, one Question related to one QuestionFigure.`(!empty($this->figure) && $this->figure->getId() === 1)` this line mean if Question  has realted to QuestionFigure and QuestionFigure id = 1 then return QuestionFigure

Comment: Ah ok - I guess the problem is that I actually have many figures that are inactive. Looks like I will need to update the model to by one to many actually...

Answer (score 0):

No! You must not have logic in your entity!

To have all question with have QuestionFigure active you must configure a repository and you implement a method.

Comment: this logic type is allowed in entity imho, for example like this in another project: https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/src/Sylius/Component/Core/Model/Product.php#L283